# On the interpretation of Fredholm's first theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely Fredholm theory of compact operators. In the text, the author gives the following proposition:

> **Proposition A** (*Fredholm's first theorem*): Let $T\colon X\to X$ be a compact operator and $X$ an infinite dimensional Banach space. Then $\operatorname{ker}T^*_{\overline{\lambda}}\neq0$ if and only if $\operatorname{ker}T_{\lambda}\neq0$.

I understand the statement of **Proposition A**. The author then gives the following *important* remark:

> **Remark 1:** Fredholm's first theorem can also be thought of as saying
> $$
> \sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}=\overline{\sigma_p(T^*)}\setminus\{0\}.
> $$

I somewhat understand what **Remark 1** is saying, but I'm not sure what the author means with the "overbar" of $\sigma_p(T^*)$, i.e. $\overline{\sigma_p(T^*)}$. Is this suppose to mean the closure of $\sigma_p(T^*)$? Or is this "abuse of notation" for saying the "complex conjugate of the set $\sigma_p(T^*)$"; that is, $\overline{\lambda}\in\sigma_p(T^*)\iff\lambda\in\overline{\sigma_p(T^*)}$? The reason I believe it's the authors short hand for saying "complex conjugate of the set $\sigma_p(T^*)$" is from the following analysis:

Let $\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}$. It follows that $\lambda\neq0$ and $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible; i.e. $\operatorname{ker}T_{\lambda}\neq\{0\}$. Thus by Fredholm's first theorem $\operatorname{ker}T^*_{\overline{\lambda}}\neq\{0\}$, i.e. $\overline{\lambda}\neq0$ and
$T^*-\overline{\lambda}I$ is not invertible. As such, $\overline{\lambda}\in\sigma_p(T^*)\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Indeed, the overline is denoting complex conjugation (by a mild abuse of notation, of a set of complex numbers) here, for the reasons you note.

Comment: @leslietownes: I see. Thanks for the clarification!